# How do I make "export default" compile to "module.exports"

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

I'm writing in typescript with it set to compile to commonjs. Whenever I put `export default`, it compiles into `exports.default` instead of `module.exports`. I am making an NPM package, so I want this to be fixed. How do I solve it? If needed, I can add my `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply write it with `module.exports` in your TS file

```
const myExportedObj = {
};

module.exports = {
    foo: myExportedObj,
};
```

Output:

```
var myExportedObj = {};
module.exports = {
    foo: myExportedObj,
};
```

---

Or, as far as I can see from your question, you could don't `export default` but `export` instead

TS

```
export const myExportedObj = {
};
```

JS

```
exports.myExportedObj = {};
```

---

Another good approach is to make an `index.ts` file and export modules from there
TS

```
export * as Context from './context';
```

JS

```
exports.Context = require("./context");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const test = ()=> 'text';
export = test;
```

compiled

```
"use strict";
const test = () => 'text';
module.exports = test;
```

[click demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/zh/play?target=99&module=1&stripInternal=false&inlineSources=false&inlineSourceMap=false&noImplicitUseStrict=false&suppressExcessPropertyErrors=false&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=false&keyofStringsOnly=false&disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect=false&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=false&noImplicitOverride=false&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=false&useDefineForClassFields=true&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&noStrictGenericChecks=true&downlevelIteration=true&allowUmdGlobalAccess=false&isolatedModules=false&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=false&importHelpers=true&removeComments=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YAoCUyB8MDkCAHlHgNwBQ8hADiAE6yoLSlA)

typescript doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require